# Ошибка при создании signal (Qt)

Tags: c++, qt

Класс:

```
class RegData
{
private:
    QString login;
    QString email;
    QString password;
public:
    RegData(QString log = "", QString mail = "", QString pass = "") : login(log), email(mail), password(pass)
    {
    }
    RegData(const RegData& src) :
        login(src.login), email(src.email), password(src.password)
    {
    }
    void cpy(const RegData& from)
    {
        login = from.login;
        email = from.email;
        password = from.password;
    }

    void output()
    {
        qDebug() << login<<email<<password;
    }
    QString getLogin()
    {
        return login;
    }
    QString getEmail()
    {
        return email;
    }
    QString getPassword()
    {
        return password;
    }

    void setLogin(const QString log)
    {
        login = log;
    }
    void setEmail(const QString mail)
    {
        email = mail;
    }
    void setPassword(const QString pass)
    {
        password = pass;
    }
signals:
    void sendObject(RegData *obj);
};
```

Когда добавляю сигналы (любые), выскакивает ошибка

> class declaration lacks q_object macro
> Exit returned ID 1

без сигналов все нормально

Answer (score 1):

Для работы с механизмом сигналов и слотов из `Qt` нужно показать фреймворку, что он должен обрабатывать этот класс с учётом того, что в нём могут быть сигналы и слоты.

Для этого наследуется класс `QObject` и в начале класса указывается макрос `Q_OBJECT`. То есть будет вот такой код:

```
#include <QObject>
class RegData : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT
```

Вам нужно почитать документации и статьи: [отличная статья для примера](https://habr.com/ru/post/50812/).

Comment: Да я делал так, выходит 10 варнингов и 5 ерроров (ерроры в qvector.h, qglobal.h кароче не в моем классе точно т.к без сигналов и слотов все нормально)

Comment: @Nedaxses читайте ошибки, в них написано, что вы делаете не так

Comment: Я работаю с несуществующим методом qvector, хотя в моем классе никаких векторов нет. Что-то еще с qglobal, хоть я его даже не подключал

Comment: @Nedaxses если заглянуть в документацию: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtglobal.html#details
`<QtGlobal> - Global Qt Declarations
 The <QtGlobal> header file includes the fundamental global declarations. It is included by most other Qtheader files.` Из чего можно сделать вывод, что этот файл есть в большинстве файлов с классами, которые предоставляет `Qt`. Я не имею много опыта работы с Qt, я бы посоветовал погуглить ошибки(на английском), скорее всего с ними уже сталкивались и находили решение.